# Angularjs unit test with $rootScope and $httpBackend

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, http, httpbackend

I have a service which fires a HTTP request. This request makes use of the $rootScope.config object (there is my base url stored), but for some reason when I use $httpBackend, $rootScope is not loaded correct.

Service:

```
myAppServices.factory('Auth', function($rootScope, $http, $cookieStore){   
  return {
    logout: function(success, error) {
      $http.get($rootScope.config.apiUrl + '/users/logout').then(function(response){
      }, function(response) {
      });
    }
```

Test:

```
describe('services', function() {
  var Auth;
  var $httpBackend;
  var $cookieStore;
  var $rootScope;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp.services');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $cookieStore = $injector.get('$cookieStore');
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    Helper = $injector.get('Helper');
    Auth = $injector.get('Auth');
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

describe('logout', function() {
  it('should make a request and invoke callback', function() {
    // I try to set $rootScope here, works in my other tests, but not in this test
    $rootScope = { config: { apiUrl: 'foo' } };

    var invoked = false;
    var success = function() {
      invoked = true;
    };
    var error = function() {};

    $httpBackend.expectPOST('/logout').respond();
    Auth.logout(success, error);
    $httpBackend.flush();
    $rootScope = { config: { apiUrl: 'foo' } };
    expect(invoked).toEqual(true);
```

It normally works when I set $rootScope in my test to some value, but not in this test.

Why is it that $rootScope does not have the config attribute in my service, when using $httpBackend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The problem:

There are two different things with the same name that cause confusion:

- There is the `$rootScope` (the actual `$rootScope` that is the ancestor of all Scopes and is injected through Angular's Dependency Injection).
- And there is a local variable named `$rootScope` that you declare in your test-suite.

For the sake of clarity, I will refer to the latter as `$rootScope{var}`.

---

Here is what's going on:

1. At some point `$rootScope` will be injected into your service's constructor (to be used later on when making the `$http` request).
2. `$rootScope{var}` is initialized to the value returned by `$injector.get('$rootScope');`.
   At this point `$rootScope` and `$rootScope{var}` are the **same** object.
3. This line: `$rootScope = { config: { apiUrl: 'foo' } };` creates a **new** object and assigns it as the value of `$rootScope{var}`.
   At this point `$rootScope` and `$rootScope{var}` are **not** the same object any more.
4. `$rootScope{var}` does have a `config` property, **but** your service is going to use `$rootScope`, which knows nothing about `config`.

---

#### The solution:

In order to add the `config` property to the actual `$rootScope` change your code like this:

```
$rootScope.config = { apiUrl: 'foo' };
```

Comment: Goodness, common JS mistake, tnx a lot for the explanation!